# Invalid pointer operation when moving TImage components at design-time

Tags: pointers, delphi, ide

I've installed Delphi 10.4 Sydney Professional Edition on a new PC, a Dell Inspiron 7400 with Win 10 Pro, i7 11 generation, 16G RAM. No other installed software by me, other than MS Office 2013.

When starting the IDE and creating a new Windows VCL application, when I add TImage components to the Form and then move them around by dragging, I randomly get an "Invalid pointer operation" error message, and then the IDE gets stuck in an endless loop requiring a <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Del</kbd> escape.

I re-installed Delphi, in case of some installation issue, but the same problem occurs.

Starting Delphi as an administrator, it behaves OK.

Has this been seen before? Is there a known fix? Looks like a bug in the IDE.

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-29570

Comment: You said you reinstalled Delphi and the problem persist. I would like to know if you have a standard Delphi installation or you added components, "experts", add-ons and anything else.

Comment: As the IDE appears to work properly when run as administrator it appears that it's related to permissions.  If you are not happy to run Delphi as administrator then you will need to try and discover what the permission problems actually are.  I would start with Procmon from SysInternals.

Comment: @fpiette - Ah, I did install Omnithreadlibrary. I'll uninstall that and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Uninstalled Omnithreadlibrary and the problem went away. Installed it again when running IDE as administrator, and that has fixed the problem. No 'Invalid pointer operation' when running Delphi not as administrator (excuse the double negative). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update. Turned out this did not fix the problem, just made it less frequent. Maybe something to do with Omnithreadlibrary but for the moment I need this installed. Just have to work on my old Win10 PC where Delphi 10.4 behaves. Ho-hum...